# Node ESM modules and Sequelize v6 initialization : "sequelize.import is not a function"

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

started a ChatApp project using Node and sequelize v6. The initilaisation package of sequelize is deprecated and i manually replaced all the requires by import.

I now get an with

```
    const model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file))
```

saying

> TypeError: sequelize.import is not a function

I know import is not a thing anymore with sequelize v6 and all i could find on the internet was answers using require. Has anyone any idea how to solve it with ESM friendly solution ?

Server.js

```
import { ApolloServer } from '@apollo/server';
import { startStandaloneServer } from '@apollo/server/standalone';
import  syncDb  from './models/index.js';

syncDb();

// The GraphQL schema
const typeDefs = `#graphql
  type Query {
    hello: String
  }
`;

// A map of functions which return data for the schema.
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    hello: () => 'world',
  },
};

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
});

const { url } = await startStandaloneServer(server);
console.log(` Server ready at ${url}`)
```

index.js

```
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import process from 'process';
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
import configDB from '../config/config.json' assert { type: "json" };;
const config = configDB[env];
const db = {};
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);
const basename = path.basename(__filename);

export default function syncDb() {
let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (
      file.indexOf('.') !== 0 &&
      file !== basename &&
      file.slice(-3) === '.js' &&
      file.indexOf('.test.js') === -1
    );
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file))
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
db.sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => console.log('Database connected!!'))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err))

return db;
}
```